# Polymer.js Data binding is not updated after setting input value with JQuery

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have the following html:

```
<img id="avatar" src="[[avatarUrl]]" />
<input id="avatar-url" type="text" placeholder="avatar url" value="{{avatarUrl::input}}" />
```

And js:

```
avatarUrl.val( profile.avatarUrl );
avatarUrl.trigger("input");
```

This code is setting the input value, but polymer doesn't update img's src attribute.

I tried triggerHandler but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of this:
value="{{avatarUrl::input}}"

you need this?
value="{{avatarUrl::change}}"

Comment: No. avatarUrl::change doesn't even react on user input.

Comment: I assumed you were using Polymer 1.0. The info I posted does work with Polymer 1.0 without any JavaScript as long as you are in a custom element or within a dom-bind element. I just tested it.

Comment: It works only after I tab new value and press Enter. I need to set new value via JS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that your use of square brackets ([[]]) is the problem. I don't have acces to the computer so I can't check it but try to change to `<img src="{{avatarUrl}}">`